# Protogen generate List<int> instead of int array

Tags: protobuf-net, protogen

Protogen (langver=3) compiles

```
repeated int32 someInt;
```

To a `int[]`.  Is there any way to force it to compile to `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>`?

Most other types (string, or custom types) compile to list.  I can implement a workaround, but the cleanest solution for me would be if this could unpack my buffer to a `List<int>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now: no, not without editing some C#.

I have on my list adding the ability to choose list/lookup types for a range of reasons including this. I'll try to make sure this gets covered in that change.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Marc!  I'll work around it for now.