# Protobuf-net generates a SomeType[] instead of List<SomeType>

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

in the .proto file I have

```
message OrderInputData
{
    /// collection of Products
    repeated double productColl = 1; 
            
   /// collection of Item
   repeated string itemsColl   = 2 ;
    
   /// collection of quantity
   repeated int32 quantityColl     = 3 ;

   /// collection of ids. if left empty, all products are going to be considered
   repeated int32  idColl       = 4;
}
```

the command to create the C# is :

```
 <Exec WorkingDirectory="..\..\ProtocolBuffers" Command="C:\protobuf-net\protogen.exe --csharp_out=..\..\ProtocolBuffers --proto_path=..\..\BCGenericAPI\DataProtocolBuffers  ClientsList.proto +names=original" />
```

it create

```
    public partial class OrderInputData : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
    {
        private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension __pbn__extensionData;
        global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
            => global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref __pbn__extensionData, createIfMissing);

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
        public double[] productColl { get; set; }

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2)]
        public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string> itemsColl { get; } = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(3)]
        public int[] quantityColl { get; set; }

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(4)]
        public int[] idColl { get; set; }

    }
```

but what I am expecting is the following

```
    public partial class OrderInputData : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
    {
        private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension __pbn__extensionData;
        global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
            => global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref __pbn__extensionData, createIfMissing);

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
       public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<double> productColl { get; } = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<double>();

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2)]
        public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string> itemsColl { get; } = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(3)]
        public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<int> quantityColl  { get; } = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(4)]
        public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<int> idColl  { get; } = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
    }
```

did I miss anything in the command to create the cs ? When I create with an old version of the Protogen it was as expected code, but not with the latest version of the Protogen

Comment: Just to note, there is this question from 2018: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770476/protogen-generate-listint-instead-of-int-array

Comment: side note: it is now *much* easier to use `protobuf-net.BuildTools` for .proto to C# code-gen: https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net/contract_first - also worth noting that you can use code-first and just lose the .proto completely

Answer (score 2):

Right now, `protobuf-net.Reflection` uses arrays for most inbuilt primitives, and lists for other types (messages, etc):

```cs
        protected virtual bool UseArray(FieldDescriptorProto field)
        {
            switch (field.type)
            {
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeBool:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeDouble:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeFixed32:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeFixed64:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeFloat:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeInt32:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeInt64:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeSfixed32:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeSfixed64:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeSint32:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeSint64:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeUint32:
                case FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TypeUint64:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

I'm happy to consider a switch to override this behaviour - it would be pretty trivial to implement - but: it doesn't exist today.

Comment: Thank you Marc, I modify my code, and all good now

Comment: @melom FYI, since it has come up multiple times, I was going to add a setting for this today, if I get a sec